# ¿Cómo almacenar muchas imágenes en la base de datos de firebase?

Tags: java, html, vue.js

Necesito subir a la base de datos de firebase muchas imágenes (más de mil), pero como puedo hacerlo si solo puedo añadirlas a firestore y luego añadir las URL de descarga una por una en el arbol de datos para obtener un .json y hacer las peticiones con axios?. Estoy utilizando un proyecto de VUE. No sé si estoy haciendo algo mal, si solo debería almacenarlas en mi proyecto o hacer otra cosa, por favor ayuda.

Ingresé una por una 151 imágenes, pero algo me dice que no fue lo correcto, porque ahora debo subir muchas, demasiadas imágenes a la base de datos. Por favor, estoy aprendiendo soy estudiante aún y de verdad me gustaría saber que hacer en esta situación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi recomendación es que crees un script que suba cada una de las imágenes de una carpeta a tu servicio de almacenamiento, que supongo es firebase storage, obtenga las url y las agregue al "árbol de datos", que supongo es firestore. Ya que estás familiarizado con javascript recomendaría que uses Node, aunque con Python tampoco debería ser difícil. Así no tendrás que subir las imágenes una por una manualmente

Comment: Entiendo amigo, lo voy a intentar. Gracias por responder !!!